Unexpected String Concatenation Issue in Airflow 2.7.2 DAG
I am encountering an unexpected issue with string concatenation in Airflow 2.7.2 using Python 3.11.5.
This problem occurs only in Airflow; the same string concatenation works correctly in local unit tests.
Here is the code snippet in DAG demonstrating the issue:
values = ['1234', '5678', 'ABC_123', 'xyz-calc', '2024-01-01',
 'NULL', '9876', 'NULL', 'example', 42, '2024-07-28T01:23:45.678',
'2024-07-28T02:34:56.789', '2024-07-28T03:45:67.890', 'user_test',
 'complete', '2024-07-28T04:56:78.901',
'2024-07-28T05:67:89.012', 'NULL',
'spark-calc-1234-driver', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'XYZ']

values_str_list = []
for value in values:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        values_str_list.append(str(value))
    elif value == 'NULL':
        values_str_list.append('NULL')
    else:
        values_str_list.append(f"'{value}'")

values_str_3 = ',\n    '.join(values_str_list)  # This concatenation does NOT work correctly
print("Concatenated string values_str_3:")
print(values_str_3)

The logs show:
[2024-07-29, 22:12:39 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Concatenated string values_str_3:
[2024-07-29, 22:12:39 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - 1234,
    5678,
    'ABC_123',
    'xyz-calc',
    '2024-01-01',
    NULL,
    '9876',
    NULL,
    'example',
    42,
    '2024-07-28T01:23:45.678',
    '2024-07-28T02:34:56.789',
    '2024-07-28T03:45:67.890',
    'user_test',
    'complete',
    '2024-07-28T04:56:78.901',
    '2024-07-28T05:67:89.012',
    NULL,
    'spark-calc-1234-driver',
    NULL,
    'XYZ'
    

The problem is that the values_str_3 string is missing one element.
Compare this
'spark-calc-1234-driver', NULL, NULL, 'XYZ'

and this
'spark-calc-1234-driver',
NULL,
'XYZ'

It is unclear why values_str_3 produces this result.
Interestingly, when I split the concatenated string, the result is correct:
print("Original string values_str_3:", values_str_3.split(',\n    '))

The logs show:
[2024-07-29, 22:12:39 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Original string values_str_3: ['1234', '5678',
 "'ABC_123'", "'xyz-calc'", "'2024-01-01'",
'NULL', "'9876'", 'NULL', "'example'", '42', "'2024-07-28T01:23:45.678'",
"'2024-07-28T02:34:56.789'", "'2024-07-28T03:45:67.890'", "'user_test'",
"'complete'", "'2024-07-28T04:56:78.901'", "'2024-07-28T05:67:89.012'", 'NULL',
"'spark-calc-1234-driver'", 'NULL', 'NULL', "'XYZ'"]

Everything appears normal.
Thank you for comments. It does seem like some kind of deduplication of strings in the logs. Here is minimal reproducible example.
values_str_3 = ',\n    '.join(['values_str_3'] * 10)
print(f"values_str_3:\n    {values_str_3}")

[2024-08-04, 08:06:08 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - values_str_3:
    values_str_3,
    values_str_3

But I can't find a setting in Airflow that controls this.

Do we care about all the rest of the code? What happens with values = ['a','NULL','NULL','b']? What about ['a','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','b']? What about just print("a\nNULL\nNULL\nb")? Please remove parts from the code until you are left with the minimal [MCVE]. My guess would be that airflow deduplicates lines. Does it happen only with NULL string? What about print('\n'.join(["string"] * 20))?

Thanks for the comment. I updated the post. I understand that with this kind of information, it is difficult for anyone to pinpoint the exact problem, but maybe someone could at least suggest what might be wrong here and what options can be tried to understand the cause of the problem?

I suspect this is per-line deduplication in the logging module. That's why you don't see it when you remove the newlines from the join.

I know nothing about Airflow but I suspect there's a configuration setting to turn off this de-duplication.

Thank you, you are right. It does seem like some kind of deduplication of strings in the logs, but I can't find a setting in Airflow that controls this. Could it be a bug?

In the end, I realized it was a bug and created a PR. I hope it gets approved because I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong with my code before I realized the issue was in Airflow.
Maybe if there are any contributors here, they could help with the approval.
